# Unwrap by selecting the class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

If I had something like this in many lines of my web page

```
<span class='red'>text</span>
```

would be possible to remove the span wrap given the classname?

like (pseudo code):

```
$('.red').removeWrap('span');
```

I  don't wanna just hide the class or removing the content

Comment: when you say "remove wrap" do you mean simply extract the "text" content of the span, or actually remove the surrounding element within the dom while still leaving the inner contents of the span?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 $('.red').contents().unwrap();
```

[**unwrap()**](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('span.red').contents().unwrap();
```